# Merging and combine columns with duplicates with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, grouping

I'm new to Python Pandas and not quite found what I need so hoping for some help. I am trying to format a file that looks something like this

```
UserId,DomainId
TestTraderCAD,ALL
TestTraderCAD,CAD
TestTraderUSD,ALL
TestTraderUSD,USD
TestTraderGBP,ALL
TestTraderGBP,GBP
```

and produce a result that groups by the UserId and produces an output as follows where I also produce a count of the number of domains for each user

```
UserId,NumDomains,Domains
TestTraderCAD,2,ALL|CAD
TestTraderUSD,2,ALL|USD
TestTraderGBP,2,ALL|GBP
```

I've tried to get started by playing around with the groupby feature but not having much luck with it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('User_Domains.csv')
#print (df)

df2 = df.groupby(['UserId'],['DomainId']).sum()
print (df2)
```

Any help to get started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `agg`

```
>>> df.groupby('UserId').agg({'UserId'  : ['first', 'count'], 
                              'DomainId': '|'.join})
```